# unable to call functions /AJAX RELATED

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update my database synchronously when the checkbox is click.
I decided to use aJax but it doesn't seems to recognize ajax.

Codes:
Elements that will be the Switch_Active(this.id) function

```
...
<div class='switch'>
<label>
Deactivate
<br>                                                        
<input  name='switch_Activate1'onclick='Switch_Activate(this.id)' type='checkbox'>
<span class='lever'></span>
<br>                                                      
Activate
</label>
</div>
...
```

THE SCRIPT

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function Switch_Activate(id) {

      if (!document.getElementById(id).checked) {
        var projectID = id;
        var Activation_Status = 1;
        var dataString = "projectID=" + projectID + "&Activation_Status=" + Activation_Status ;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/switchchange.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            alert("asd1");
            }
        });

      }
      else{
        var projectID = id;
        var Activation_Status = 1;
        var dataString = "projectID=" + projectID + "&Activation_Status=" + Activation_Status ;

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/switchchange.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
          alert("asd2");
            }
        });
      }

    }//
</script>
```

switchchange.php

```
<?php

 include("../../connection/connection.php");
    echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('php in');</script>";
    $projectID = $_POST['projectID'];
    $Account_Status = $_POST['Activation_Status'];
    $sql = "update tblProject set projectStatus = '$Account_Status' where projectID = '$Account_Status'";
    $stmnt = sqlsrv_query($db, $sql);
    ?>
```

CONNECTION

```
    <?php

    //Database Connection
try{
    $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=AJ-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=RealEstate_DB", "", "");
    $db -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOExceptio $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Comment: Is code control coming inside of `switch_Activate1` ?

Comment: Your PHP is actually echoing out a script tag, which will never work, as you're expecting to get JSON data back. Return valid JSON, and put the alert in the success callback for the `$.ajax` function instead

Comment: You also have syntax errors, for instance `if (...) { code } } else { code }`

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library?

Comment: Yes I included it.

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: Yes. But it only shows errors about css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite your code in this manner, making sure you follow these steps:

1. Make sure you include jQuery
2. why use `this.id` if you can simply use `this` which will give you all you need about that element's object
3. you are using the same code in your if/else conditions, all you need to do is build your `dataString` with the necessary options, then pass the data to AJAX once.
4. no `return false` is needed as clicking on a checkbox will not trigger anything else.

Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="someID" name='switch_Activate1' onclick='Switch_Activate(this)' type='checkbox'>

<script>
    function Switch_Activate(checkbox) {

        var dataString = {
            'project_ID': checkbox.id,
            'Activation_Status': checkbox.checked
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/switchchange.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            done: function (data) {
                alert(data.message);
                if (data.response) {
                    // your success code
                } else {
                    // your error code
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Update:

I just realized your AJAX call is set to accept JSON `dataType: "json"` but your PHP is not outputting JSON. You need to convert all output to JSON, so in your case you can do something like this:

```
<?php
// ... your Database UPDATE code...

$result = array(
    "response" => TRUE,
    "message" => "some message"
);
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: It's not reading ajax. I tried putting `   echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('php in');</script>";
` on my php file to see if it reads it but it doesn't

Comment: what do you mean by "not reading ajax"? do you mean Javascript is not working at all?

Comment: Javascript is working. I add an alert before `$.ajax` part. And the alert did pop up. But ajax seems not to work or changing the value in the database.

Comment: Tried it but still not working. I tried removing the `dataType:json`  it alert the success(function) although it didn't do anything on my DB. It seems to not recognize my PHP file `switchchange.php`.

Comment: updated my answer again to show more info. try it again

Comment: I tried adding an error message on my success(data):
alert(data);

Comment: It gives me this error message` warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in ...`

Comment: provide the contents of `connection.php`

Comment: according to the docs, `sqlsrv_query()` accepts a connection resource returned by `sqlsrv_connect()`, however your `$db` is not created by that..   http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

Comment: since you are using PDO you need to do run your queries this way: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Comment: FATAL ERROR : Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: Tried to bind parameter number 0.'..

Comment: I don't know who you are but thank you  for having a long patience for me. It's working now :)  Thank you so much. I learned a lot from you!

Comment: Cool. glad I was able to help. :)